# How do I select columns based on their type in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame in R with many columns (over 50+). The column types are integer, factor, and character. Is there a fast way to only select all the character columns for my dataframe?

I tried something like below but it didn't work.  :/

Example: new_dataset <- class(old_dataset) %in% c("character")  #only select characters

Comment: `old_dataset[sapply(old_dataset, is.character)]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dplyr::select_if()` is superseded by `dplyr::select(where(...))` in the `dplyr` 1.0.0

To select columns where type is `character` use:

```r
library(dplyr)
storms %>% select(where(is.character)) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

```
Rows: 10,010
Columns: 2
$ name   <chr> "Amy", "Amy", "Amy", "Amy"...
$ status <chr> "tropical depression", "tropical depression"...
```

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  char = c("hi there", "how're you", "what's up"),
  int = 1:3,
  fac = c("A", "B", "C"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ char: chr  "hi there" "how're you" "what's up"
 $ int : int  1 2 3
 $ fac : chr  "A" "B" "C"
```

You can select columns by subsetting the dataframe by datatype, thus:

```
df[sapply(df, is.character)]
        char fac
1   hi there   A
2 how're you   B
3  what's up   C
```

Here, `sapply` applies the function `is.character`to each of the columns in `df`. The function itself runs a test - Is the column of type 'character'? - and returns TRUE or FALSE accordingly.

Comment: If it is helpful, as you say, do consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: Hey Chris; I gave this a go but my reputation is still less than 15.  So it records but isn't publicly shown yet.

Comment: @ChadLongwood No prob. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::select_if` can help you.

For instance, this gets you all columns of type `character` in table `t`:

```
> t %>% 
    select_if(is.character) %>% 
    glimpse()

Rows: 199,303
Columns: 6
$ user_type     <chr> "registered", "registered", "registered", "registered",…
$ location      <chr> "Massachusetts", "United States", "South Africa", "Loui…
$ website_url   <chr> "http://caerwyn.com", "http://www.berbs.us", "http://tu…
$ link          <chr> "https://stackoverflow.com/users/2406/caerwyn", "https:…
$ profile_image <chr> "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0983795ba79aaa48a86752…
$ display_name  <chr> "caerwyn", "berberich", "tumbleweed", "Nate", "Ryan", "…
```

Replacing `is.character` with `is.numeric`, `is.logical` etc. gets your what you need.